# Is there any limit to the utility of quantum measurements in the sense of a Lieb-Robinson bound?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, research-level, quantum-measurements, locality, non-locality

So the Lieb-Robinson bound of 1972 derives an *emergent* maximum speed $v \ll c$ of the propagation of quantum information under time evolution generated by some local Hamiltonian $H(t)$. Basically, transmitting quantum information over a distance $L$ or preparing an entangled / correlated state of qubits separated by maximum distance $L$ is *only* possible after a time $t \gtrsim L/v$, where $v$ is the Lieb-Robinson velocity. And I guess this has been extended to power-law Hamiltonians and other contexts, including Lindblad dynamics in [*Phys. Rev. Lett.* **104** 190401 (2010)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3675).

However, recent works such as [*PRX Quantum* **3**, 040337 (2022)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.13527), [arXiv:2112.01519](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.01519), [arXiv:2112.03061](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.03061), [arXiv:2208.11136](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.11136) seem to suggest that projective and weak measurements sidestep this bound entirely (even local ones). For example, these works present protocols that prepare many-body states on $L$ qubits in finite depth using local measurements, and I'm also aware that quantum teleportation with local measurements and feedback is possible using finite-depth circuits for *any* distance $L$. In this sense, measurements are "nonlocal" in a nonrelativistic sense, which could be fine.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is the claim of these works (or general consensus of the community) that local measurements provide a loophole to the Lieb-Robinson bound? In other words, that there may be no notion of nonrelativistic locality when measurements are involved, even if the measurements act locally?
2. Are there other works in the literature that offer similar
   evidence or make similar claims that local measurements and feedback avoid the usual
   Lieb-Robinson bound (and corresponding notion of locality)?
3. Is it correct to say that the reason that the Lindblad bounds are equivalent to the bounds for (unitary) time evolution alone is that in the Lindblad setting, the outcomes of the measurements are not utilized (i.e., no feedback), while in the various protocols above (and in the context of teleportation), the use of outcomes is important?
4. Are there reasons to believe there is any limit to this loophole provided by local measurements---i.e., is the combination of local projective measurements and outcome-dependent feedback *arbitrarily* nonlocal, making it an extremely powerful resource? Or is there reason to believe that some altered notion of locality exists?

I am particularly interested in any other references people may have come across that make claims or conjectures on this topic, or if there is debate on this subject (i.e., conflicting claims about the [non]locality of measurements).